# facebook like button not displaying :: FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init()

Tags: facebook, html, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I just want a basic facebook like button on my site. I follow the instructions per facebooks site (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). I tried the `HTML5`, `XFBML`, and `iFrame` ways, no joy on either. So I thought maybe it's something with my site interfering. So I created a bare-bones html page like below and it still gives me the `FB.getLoginStatus()` called before calling `FB.init()` error.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/[mypage]" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: I removed all that stuff above went back to the `iFrame` only method and it works, but only in Firefox. Chrome and IE9 I still get nothing but no errors reported. Why is this line below only working in FireFox (obviously the [myPage] part is swapped out)?

```
 <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F[myPage]&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: You have not given an app id when embedding the JS SDK – but it’s mandatory, otherwise it can not be initialized properly.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  Little progress but still not there.  So I see where facebook says: You will need an app ID to initialize the SDK, which you can obtain from the App Dashboard.  "App Dashboard" is a link pointing to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/  but when I click the dang thing it keeps redirecting me to https://www.facebook.com/[mysite]

Comment: You’ll have to verify your account with FB first, before you can create apps.

Comment: Sorry, still not understanding.  My account is verified, people have already liked me in the past.  Why do I need a app ID, I don't want any apps.  I just want people to like my page.  My page is not a personal page but a business page, does that matter?

Comment: If you don’t want to use an app, then use the iframe version of the like button plugin – that does not need an app id to be given in the parameters.

Comment: Have you resolved this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I am also having the same problem. I can't find anywhere to create an app, just keeps going around in circles. I also get the same error after trying to implement the like button

Comment: Where do we add the app_id?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure the App ID is the problem here. I'm also experiencing this *strange* error message, and I'm just including standard code for FB Like Button social plugin, provided by FB developer page.

I then went again through the [plugin configuration page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) and copied again code, which anyway was unchanged <strike>noticing little difference in the HTML part of generated code (was a `<fb:like>` tag, now is `<div class="fb-like">`)</strike>. 
Anyway error still persists.

Then I just realised that in a few weeks FB Like Button will migrate permanently to *Built-in Like action for Open Graph*, and if I got it correctly you **have** to create an App ID anyway.

At that point the error might just disappear. And it seems difficult that anyone will fix anything on something that's going to *disappear* in a few weeks.

HTH

Comment: Just experienced the exact same thing. Creating a test app and using that app id fixed it. Maybe Facebook have moved to the "must have an app id" thing already?

Answer (score 2):

Are you testing it locally? After debugging and searching quite a bit myself, I decided to test it on a webserver of mine, and voila, it worked! :)

Answer (score 1):

On the Facebook Developer page where we obtain the script for the Like Button, Facebook says nothing of needing to implement the init() as well (which would presumably solve this problem, but what WOULD you use as the APP ID if you also called the init() function ??).

And an APP ID is not needed anyway for the Like Button to work. I believe that Facebook is just giving us the Like Button code -- even though the absence of the init() function is going to cause this js error (but apparently the init() is not actually needed!).

This seems like a shortcoming in FB's deployment of the Like Button API.