# FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init()

Tags: facebook

I've this message in my console

```
FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().
```

My code

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
           if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = \"//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1\";
           ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
         }(document));
</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

I don't understand why. I've only one call of this facebook like plugin in all my website.

Answer (score 90):

### Short answer

Add `&status=0` to your `js.src` URL to make the warning disappear, ie:

`//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1&status=0`

### Full answer

`FB.init()` will be called internally by the facebook script upon loading if parameters are provided after the hash (#) sign.  Here `xfbml` is passed, so `FB.init()` is called.

(source code: http://connect.facebook.net/fr_CA/all/debug.js line 8699 at the time of this post)

The default args for init() are used if not explicitly provided: `status` arg default is `true` - which makes the FB script call `getLoginStatus()` at startup, which complains because an app ID is needed for that function call.

**FB social plugins doesn't need an app ID** - they are rendered into an iframe originating from facebook.com, so FB login status and cookies as accessible to them.

The "Get the Code" wizards in the [FB developers Social Plug-ins section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/#configurator) generates a URL with the `xfbml` param, it should be updated with the `status=0` param IMHO.

Comment: If you copy pasted the URL you need to change 'fr_FR' to 'en_US' to use English. Just in case anyone wondered.

Comment: Does not seem to work for the sdk.js. The new version of the FB api.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the warning of 'Invalid App ID' after implementing solution of

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16593474/1428052

then add appId to your js.src URL to make it work for you, i.e.:

> //connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&status=0&appId=YOUR_APP_ID

The presence of this appId, will automatically call FB.init() with basic app settings.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: some speculation below. If that's not OK, I can delete it.

I'd assume that the problem lies in loading the SDK asynchronously but the Like button inline. Then it's possible that the Like button calls getLoginStatus before the script has loaded. You can test/verify this by commenting out the script to load the SDK asynchronously and instead include it as a normal script tag in the page head.

Of course, that's just the easy way to test. If you can verify that as the problem, the "proper" way to solve it would probably be to ensure that the Like button doesn't appear on the page until the SDK has loaded.

Comment: That makes sense, but I guess "Asynchronously" means "Do not slow page rendering". Shouldn't "FB.getLoginStatus" be called async, after FB.init, by sdk itself?

Comment: I've just realized that I should have asked an impt question before giving this answer: Does that message appear in the console as soon as the page loads, or only when you click the Like button, or at some other point (e.g., when the Like button gets rendered)? My assumption is that FB.init is called as part of async SDK loading, & getLoginStatus is called when the Like button is clicked or loaded.

Comment: Since I have the same issue, i'll answer : the console notice:"[16:49:03,243] FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init(). @ http://connect.facebook.net/fr_CA/all.js#xfbml=1:56" is triggered exactly where the like button is parsed in the HTML code (before document ready)

Comment: Yes that's it, as soon as the page load.
I don't understand, I pick up the code on the facebook dev page ... https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#plugins With the iframe code no problem.

Comment: _“I'd assume that the problem lies in loading the SDK asynchronously but the Like button inline.”_ – no, that can’t be it. Until the SDK executes, there __is__ no like button – it’s the SDK’s job to parse the `<div class="fb-like">` element and turn it into an iframe. Before the SDK runs, this is just an HTML element that does nothing on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I answered to a similar SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12911928/540776).
Actually, if you also cannot see the Like button at all, then this question is an exact duplicate of the other one.

In my case, I'm seeing the console error, but I *do* see the Like button as well.

Comment: I have the same problem, done everything like the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) step by step and I see the button but get the console error `FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().` anyway. Any solutions yet?

Comment: I added my own answer as well to that question. I got it solved by testing it online. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `FB.init` function before the calling fb login status function

```html
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script> 
    <script>
      FB.init({
            appId  : 'YOUR APP ID',
            status : true, // check login status
            cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml  : true,  // parse XFBML
            oauth : true
        });

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = \"//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1\";
       ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
     }(document));
  </script>
```

Comment: Gives: `ReferenceError: FB is not defined`

Comment: It gives the error: FB.init has already been called - this could indicate a problem

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using this code:

```html
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js?xfbml=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js#xfbml=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <div class="fb-like"
          data-href="https://www.myurl.com" 
          data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" 
          data-width="50" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

Comment: This isn't asynchronous though; it's blocking.