# Facebook Like button not counting correctly and not picking up already clicked Like

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I have a website with a Facebook Like button on the landing page of the domain using the below code

```
<!-- FB button code -->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&status=0";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<!-- FB button code end -->
```

which is the default code supplied by FB, and where the &status=0 was added as per [FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810018/fb-getloginstatus-called-before-calling-fb-init)

and the code to the actual button is

```
<li><div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.vinner.com.au" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div></li>
```

This was working okay for a while but any new likes on the FB page itself suddenly stopped at 26 and my like of the page is registered as the screenshot below

[image]

however the actual website reset the Like count to a lower number, and I'm able to relike the page (and I'm logged into FB on the same browse)

[image]

I've raised a bug with FB but they don't respond to individual requests, so hoping someone out there can identify if I've done something wrong in my config, and can explain why I have a different Like count, and why I'm able to relike a page I've already liked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/) of Like Button, the `data-href` property is -

> The absolute URL of the page that will be liked.

You are giving it the url to your website, i.e. `http://www.vinner.com.au`, and expecting it to sync with the likes of your facebook page. How is this possible?

The liking an external url and liking a facebook page are two different things.

To sync your facebook page's likes with your like button - you should provide url of your fb page to the like button-

```
.... data-href="{link-to-your-fb-page}" ....
```

Comment: Thanks that was the issue, looks like I'd somehow changed that doing a recent release.