# auto-creating FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init()

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I am getting this error in Safari and other browsers:

The "fb-root" div has not been created, auto-creating

all.js:52

FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().

all.js:52

In my header I have this:

```
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
 xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"  
 xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
 xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>

<meta property=""fb:admins"" content=""508331528"" />
<meta property=""fb:page_id"" content=""118806721611355"" />
<meta property=""fb:app_id"" content=""426360900751901"" />
```

(I realize I should not have all three property tags, but I have tried various scenarios)

In the body of the page I have these two simple facebook tags:

```
<fb:like data-href="http://www.PrintMyWatercolor.com" layout="button_count" style="width: 90px;" data-show-faces="true" data-send="true" action="recommend"></fb:like>

<fb:comments href="http://www.PrintMyWatercolor.com" numposts="25" width="590"></fb:comments>
```

As far as I understand, this should be ok. I don't have any explicit javascript code for facebook on the page. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Looks like an AppID is mandatory. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514936/facebook-like-button-not-displaying-fb-getloginstatus-called-before-calling

Answer (score 3):

1. You don't appear (from that sample ) to have the `<div id="fb-root"></div>` which the Javascript SDK attaches itself to
2. Your method of loading the Javascript SDK isn't asynchronous so the SDK may be loading before the page has finished, use the method [from the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) instead, which works by attaching the SDK once the rest of the document has loaded

Comment: Thanks, that does get rid of the error. I thought the header linked js would insert that standard code. However, I get a new error: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains. I am assuming this has to do with the fact I am running on a Dev IIS Server with the url DevMySite rather than the final true url. Is there a way to get rid of the error or let FB know about the dev site urls? (if that is the prob)

Comment: I think admins of the app can override that restriction, but otherwise no - you'd need to use a different app ID which has your dev server specified as the website - there's no support on Facebook's side for separate production/staging/development environments linked to the same App ID

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll try to set up a testing AppId. You have helped a lot!