# Link like button to an existing Facebook page, other answers not helping, I've looked

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, facebook-like

I promise you I have been working on this for hours.

Error is:

> Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

I have a 1 page website, it is only in development and the current URL is only for testing purposes, it is possible this is part of the problem and it work on the live site but I have no way of checking this at this stage.

I have a Facebook business page already, this is also not the actual page it will go to however; it is one I will be using with my own site later. This one is for a client, which is why I do not have all the details yet.

1. I have logged in to Facebook, created a Facebook developers App, which currently links to nothing as far as I can tell and I don't know how to do this. Tried using 'Page Tab' but it didn't seem like the right thing and I don't know what it is or how it works?
2. I have followed all the steps for creating the button I want, copied the HTML5 and JavaScript and changed the app ID, tried both the one from my apps and the page ID from the Facebook page. Neither worked, no button shows.
3. Tried using the iFrame version, with and without JavaScript code, still nothing.

Long story short, I have no idea what to do, I'm not using WordPress and no instructions I have found make sense because I have never done this before. It's supposed to be easy? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514936/facebook-like-button-not-displaying-fb-getloginstatus-called-before-calling?rq=1 This was probably the closest question to mine, but doesn't provide an answer. I am using a server not local, so that is not part of the problem, will try it on a page with none of my other code, but to be honest, I'm not expecting any change, there's nothing on my page already that should affect it

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up at least one "platform" in your app's settings, whether it may be Canvas of Website or something else. If you set the App Domain, it must be the same as your Canvas or Website URL is using, e.g.

- App Domain: www.test.com
- Canvas URL: www.test.com/fb/greatapp/

Comment: I was wondering if that might be something to do with it, never got around to testing since I do still have the rest of the site to do, I'll let you know if this solves the issue once it's done, thanks